# Keras - Why Validation data produce good results, while unseen data is performing poorly

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, overfitting

I've built a feedforward net that predicts 2 classes (0,1). I've used the validation_split attribute like so:

```
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=validation_split_ratio, epochs=700, batch_size=10, verbose=1, callbacks=[tb, checkpoint])
```

I got strange results (validation performs better than the train data):

[image] [image]

I then took the validation data used for the training (20% from the last samples in my dataset) and tested the model to build a confusion matrix:

[image]

But when I trying to build a confusion matrix from new unseen data, my model performs poorly.

[image]

**Why is that?** I thought the validation data used by Keras is also "unseen" by the model.

**UPDATE Visualization code:**

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import itertools

def create_model():
    ## Create our model
    model = Sequential()
    # 0.81250

    model.add(Dense(44, input_dim=18, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.8))
    model.add(Dense(44, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    return model


def load_trained_model(weights_path):
    model = create_model()
    model.load_weights(weights_path)
    return model

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')


dataset = np.loadtxt("./validation/validation.csv", skiprows=1, delimiter=",")
model = load_trained_model('./checkpoints/weights.best.hdf5')
X = dataset[:, :18]
Y = dataset[:, [18]]


Y_pred = model.predict(X)
print(Y_pred)

y_pred = model.predict_classes(X)
print(y_pred)

p = model.predict_proba(X)  # to predict probability

target_names = ['class 0','class 1']
print(classification_report(Y, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(Y, y_pred)
print(cnf_matrix)
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=target_names,normalize=True,
                      title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')
plt.show()
```

**Dataset sample:**

```
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,5,1,6.01,4.86,43.0,1,2,1
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,117,3,1,5.02,4.86,54.0,0,2,1
0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,6.01,4.86,70.0,1,2,0
```

Last column is the label (1 or 0)

Comment: Can you post more of your code please? How do you load the data? Are their any differences between your methods of preprocessing?

Comment: Same preprocessing, check my updates for the visualization code.

Comment: When you create the .csv files how do you determine what data goes into `validation.csv` or `test.csv`? Are they drawn from the same distribution. I would suggest to put all the data into a single file if that's possible then split them randomly using the sklearn train_test split function.

Comment: Seems like a case if data leakage

Comment: The split is done automatically by Keras, then I'm taking the same amount of data in order to create the matrix. @Aditya how can I avoid data leakage but still validate the model while training.

Comment: @JahKnows What do you think about the first dropout? Lower your dropout on the first layer `.8` is so high that's it's not even seeing anything(80% of your inputs are lost after the first layer..)..Also you don't apply such high dropout directly next to your input layers... Kindly have a reframing of your architecture by looking at the docs or online.., you can also play with your activation functions... Also what's your dataset look like??

Comment: Normalisation is kind of must in a neural net especially if you are having mixed scaling of your inputs..

Comment: This can happen when using dropout. Dropout is activated on training but not on validation, resulting in a smoother function on validation compared to training. See here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/205831

Comment: But isn't the dropout deactivated automatically during predictions?